# Cannot get SVG to properly float-left in cards within BootStrap project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, css-float

I am currently working on a project for a job application where I need to recreate the stripe.com website using bootstrap. I am currently struggling on the following portion of the website:

[image]

Unfortunately, my current works is as such:

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the svgs to float left in each card so that the header and paragraph elements display directly to their right rather than below them.

So far I have tried using CSS and boot-strap classes to make the SVG elements float left with no success, and after 45 minutes of googling I decided I should ask stckOflw. Here is my current relevant code:

```css
.card-section{
    background-color: #F6F9FC;
}

.card-section svg{
    height: 130px;
    width:130px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: -35px;
    /* float: left; */
}

.green-card h5{
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .025em;
    color: #24b47e;
}

.blue-card h5{
      margin: 0 0 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .025em;
    color: #3297d3;
}

.card-section p{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #525f7f;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;  
}



.card-section .card{
    overflow:hidden;
    /* padding: 40px 40px 40px 120px; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="card-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="card green-card">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 130 130" class="float-left">
                            <path class="hover-fillLight" fill="#76E5A2"
                                d="M65 10c30.376 0 55 24.624 55 55s-24.624 55-55 55-55-24.624-55-55 24.624-55 55-55z"></path>
                            <path fill="#FFF"
                                d="M102.274 27.78v-.002c-9.628-9.615-22.968-15.526-37.69-15.408-28.292.228-51.557 23.072-52.238 51.32-.22 9.175 1.915 17.832 5.84 25.416.1.192.317.29.526.24.003 0 .006 0 .01-.002a.462.462 0 0 0 .324-.616c-5.15-13.598-2.25-29.54 8.713-40.488 14.915-14.898 39.102-14.898 54.02 0L48.25 81.725c14.917 14.897 39.104 14.897 54.022 0 14.916-14.897 14.917-39.048.002-53.945z">
                            </path>
                            <path class="hover-fillDark" fill="#159570"
                                d="M88.198 58.794c3.435 12.802-4.173 25.96-16.992 29.39-12.82 3.43-25.997-4.166-29.43-16.968-3.436-12.802 4.17-25.96 16.99-29.39 12.82-3.43 25.997 4.166 29.43 16.968z">
                            </path>
            
                        </svg>
                        <h5 class="">Recuring Payments</h5>
                        <p class="">
                            Send Invoices, manage subscriptions and reduce payment declines with Stripe's recovery tools. Explore Stripe Billing.
                        </p>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card blue-card">
                        <svg class="float-left" viewBox="0 0 130 130">
                            <path class="hover-fillLight" fill="#69D5F8"
                                d="M65 10c30.376 0 55 24.624 55 55s-24.624 55-55 55-55-24.624-55-55 24.624-55 55-55z"></path>
                            <path fill="#FFF"
                                d="M48 79.552V47.998H34.73c-.65 0-1.275.26-1.735.72L13.765 68.07a3.7 3.7 0 0 0-1.053 3.068c2.92 23.81 22.293 43.188 46.103 46.114a3.7 3.7 0 0 0 3.067-1.052L81.29 97.05c.46-.46.717-1.084.717-1.735L82 82l-31.545.005A2.454 2.454 0 0 1 48 79.552z">
                            </path>
                            <path class="hover-fillDark" fill="#217AB7"
                                d="M119.55 58.073L96.344 81.28c-.46.46-1.085.72-1.736.72H81.993V50.462a2.454 2.454 0 0 0-2.453-2.455H48l.002-12.613c0-.65.258-1.276.718-1.736L71.93 10.45c24.83 3.123 44.497 22.79 47.62 47.623z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
                       
                            <h5>PAYMENTS FOR PLATFORMS</h5>
                            <p>
                                Stripe Connect gives platforms and marketplaces the tools to easily support multi-party payments and get sellers in
                                25 counties paid.
                            </p>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

One thing that I've discovered is that when I try to use float: left; on my CSS for my SVG elements within my cards, and then I remove bootstrap, they work. However, bootstrap is required for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.card-section {
  background-color: #F6F9FC;
}

.card-section svg {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: -35px;
  /* float: left; */
  flex: 0 0 130px;
}

.green-card h5 {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .025em;
  color: #24b47e;
}

.blue-card h5 {
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .025em;
  color: #3297d3;
}

.card-section p {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #525f7f;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

.card-section .card {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center
  /* padding: 40px 40px 40px 120px; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card green-card">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 130 130">
                            <path class="hover-fillLight" fill="#76E5A2"
                                d="M65 10c30.376 0 55 24.624 55 55s-24.624 55-55 55-55-24.624-55-55 24.624-55 55-55z"></path>
                            <path fill="#FFF"
                                d="M102.274 27.78v-.002c-9.628-9.615-22.968-15.526-37.69-15.408-28.292.228-51.557 23.072-52.238 51.32-.22 9.175 1.915 17.832 5.84 25.416.1.192.317.29.526.24.003 0 .006 0 .01-.002a.462.462 0 0 0 .324-.616c-5.15-13.598-2.25-29.54 8.713-40.488 14.915-14.898 39.102-14.898 54.02 0L48.25 81.725c14.917 14.897 39.104 14.897 54.022 0 14.916-14.897 14.917-39.048.002-53.945z">
                            </path>
                            <path class="hover-fillDark" fill="#159570"
                                d="M88.198 58.794c3.435 12.802-4.173 25.96-16.992 29.39-12.82 3.43-25.997-4.166-29.43-16.968-3.436-12.802 4.17-25.96 16.99-29.39 12.82-3.43 25.997 4.166 29.43 16.968z">
                            </path>
            
                        </svg>
          <div class="content_wrap">
            <h5 class="">Recuring Payments</h5>
            <p class="">
              Send Invoices, manage subscriptions and reduce payment declines with Stripe's recovery tools. Explore Stripe Billing.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card blue-card">
          <svg class="float-left" viewBox="0 0 130 130">
                            <path class="hover-fillLight" fill="#69D5F8"
                                d="M65 10c30.376 0 55 24.624 55 55s-24.624 55-55 55-55-24.624-55-55 24.624-55 55-55z"></path>
                            <path fill="#FFF"
                                d="M48 79.552V47.998H34.73c-.65 0-1.275.26-1.735.72L13.765 68.07a3.7 3.7 0 0 0-1.053 3.068c2.92 23.81 22.293 43.188 46.103 46.114a3.7 3.7 0 0 0 3.067-1.052L81.29 97.05c.46-.46.717-1.084.717-1.735L82 82l-31.545.005A2.454 2.454 0 0 1 48 79.552z">
                            </path>
                            <path class="hover-fillDark" fill="#217AB7"
                                d="M119.55 58.073L96.344 81.28c-.46.46-1.085.72-1.736.72H81.993V50.462a2.454 2.454 0 0 0-2.453-2.455H48l.002-12.613c0-.65.258-1.276.718-1.736L71.93 10.45c24.83 3.123 44.497 22.79 47.62 47.623z">
                            </path>
                        </svg>
          <div class="content_wrap">
            <h5>PAYMENTS FOR PLATFORMS</h5>
            <p>
              Stripe Connect gives platforms and marketplaces the tools to easily support multi-party payments and get sellers in 25 counties paid.
            </p>
            <div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```